# Setting an alarm (as in alarm clock) using intents

Tags: android, clock, alarms

Since API level 9 (2.3) you can set an alarm using an intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 9);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 37);
startActivity(i);
```

Is there anyway of setting an alarm in a similar fashion (undocumented APIs?) for lower API levels?

Also if anyone knows any similar methods for non-stock alarmclocks ([such as ones listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590955/intent-to-launch-the-clock-application-on-android) I.E. HTC Alarm Clock, Moto Blur Alarm Clock etc...) I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all my further research I could find no way of doing so, so I assume the answer is **NO** until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is obvious but I just want to be sure - have you considered using the AlarmManager?
[Android.com example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html)

Comment: AlarmManager is not used to set the alarm clock, it is used for scheduling services to run. Annoyingly it just has a name of what you'd expect for setting the alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this works exactly. I had tried it but does anyone know if I can cancel that alarm clock timing from my application?

As for your question, no. But I think it's not possible to use in lower API's as it works only above Level 9.

The `android.provider.AlarmClock` cannot be recognized in lower levels.