# Android Permission denied - com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to set a Alarm from my app, but when I start the intent by doing the following, as described here: [How to launch Alarm Clock screen using Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664670/how-to-launch-alarm-clock-screen-using-intent-in-android)

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
Intent alarmas = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
alarmas.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Prueba Custom Alarm Clock");
alarmas.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10);
alarmas.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
startActivity(alarmas);
return true;
}
```

I get this exception:

```
08-09 18:23:42.782    7461-7461/? E/AndroidRuntime: Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-09 18:23:42.927    7461-7461/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException:     Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM cmp=com.urbandroid.sleep/.alarmclock.AddAlarmActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{442bf618 7461:com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock/10067} (pid=7461, uid=10067) requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1214)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
at  com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock.ClockActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ClockActivity.java:109)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:525)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1694)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I don't know why it's asking for "com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" because that is set in my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  >
    <activity
        android:name="com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock.ClockActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your manifest declares the package '`com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock`' for which it requests `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM`. However, in your stacktrace the permission error comes from `com.urbandroid.sleep/.alarmclock.AddAlarmActivity`

You need to ensure that com.urbandroid.sleep has said permission.

Comment: com.urbandroid.sleep package is from the app "Sleep as Android", why the permission error comes from there if I am trying to use my APP to set the alarm using the System 'ś default app? (I don't know if this is what I am currently doing, maybe the problem is because i don't tell my app to use the default app, wich I don't know how to do). My package is "com.TurryBoeing.customalarmclock".

Comment: hi @TurryBoeing, I have the exact same issue with you, do you have a solution for it now?