# Android reminder intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, reminders

Is it possible to open creating reminder using intent like
an event?
I couldn't find any solution.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to invoke this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664670/how-to-launch-alarm-clock-screen-using-intent-in-android

Comment: I think he means more like a calendar entry.

Comment: @Nathanael I don't want to make an alarm, that is why I posted image. If you open google calendar, you can add event, reminder and the newest feature is goal. I want to invoke new reminder. Probably it is not possible, but I wanted to be sure I did not miss anything in documentation.

Comment: did you find a solution to add or set default minutes for reminder using intent?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this. All you need to do is, call this method, and it will take care of the rest.

```
public static void pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, 
                                              String title, long startDate) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startDate);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", startTime+24*60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    curActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But before that, make sure you have these permissions manifested.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

If you are using Android API 23 (6.0) or above, I recommend you to read about the new permission model in API 23 [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). And make sure to request in runtime, which will be good for your app to support future versions of android.

**UPDATE**

You should try this as suggested by [Sanjeev Kumar in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934306/3073612)

```
 /** Adds Events and Reminders in Calendar. */
 private void addReminderInCalendar() {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "events");
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
 
     /** Inserting an event in calendar. */
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Sanjeev Reminder 01");
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "A test Reminder.");
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
     // event starts at 11 minutes from now
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 1 * 60 * 1000);
     // ends 60 minutes from now
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 2 * 60 * 1000);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
     values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
     Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
 
     // Display event id.
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event added :: ID :: " + event.getLastPathSegment(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 
     /** Adding reminder for event added. */
     Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "reminders");
     values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
     values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
     values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);
     cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
 }
 
 /** Returns Calendar Base URI, supports both new and old OS. */
 private String getCalendarUriBase(boolean eventUri) {
     Uri calendarURI = null;
     try {
         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
             calendarURI = (eventUri) ? Uri.parse("content://calendar/") :
             Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
         } else {
             calendarURI = (eventUri) ? Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/") : Uri
                     .parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return calendarURI.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Oh remainders, will change accordingly

Comment: I appreciate, you are trying to help, but there is no problem of making a event and reminder for this event, I want to invoke reminder, like when you use Google now, or you just add reminder in Google calendar. Probably it's not possible, at least for now.