# How to open alarm settings on tapping analog clock in android

Tags: android, widget

I have created an analog clock widget for Android 4. Now I want to mimic the same behavior as the native analog clock widget, which is to show the alarm settings window on tapping the clock.

After searching I found this topic:
 [Intent to launch the clock application on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590955/intent-to-launch-the-clock-application-on-android)

Which launches the desktop clock and not the alarm settings. I think I have to do something with android.provider.AlarmClock but I can not get it to launch the alarms window. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my `AppWidgetProvider` class, the following works for me on 4.1.2 (provided you only want it to work on 4.x - otherwise you will need conditional logic to select the right package and class names for the appropriate version, like in the post you linked to):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                getAlarmPackage(context), 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.analogClock1, pendingIntent);

        AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(context)
                .updateAppWidget(
                        intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS),
                        views);
    }
}

private Intent getAlarmPackage(Context context) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    try {
        ComponentName c = new ComponentName("com.google.android.deskclock",
                "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock");
        manager.getActivityInfo(c, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        intent.setComponent(c);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException nf) {
        Log.d("XXXX", "Caught name not found exception!");
    }

    return intent;
}
```

Basically, using `com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock` (with `com.google.android.deskclock`) instead of `com.android.deskclock.DeskClock` produces the Alarms list instead of the Alarm clock screen.