# Adding PendingIntent onClick to Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, customdialog

I'm a copy and paste coder, this may be really silly...

I have a custom dialog that comes up after my widget is clicked:

```
public class ClockHandler extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.clockhandler);
        dialog.setTitle("Available Clocks...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button 
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("System Clocks");
        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for System Clock...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Trying to open System Clock
        // referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/805031
            }
        });

        TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text2.setText("More Clock Widgets!");

        text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clock Widget Gallery Coming SOON!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Open clock widget gallery
        // eventually
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

I'd like to implement https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/805031 solution when `TextView text` is clicked. I have tried all sorts of arrangements, including:

using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/805031 in a separate file `SystemClock.java` and then trying to call that from my `ClockHandler` with things like

```
final RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clockhandler);
                final PendingIntent intent = SystemClock.getClockIntent(context);
                if (intent != null){
                    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.text, intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
                  PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

and also including the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/805031 solution in the ClockHandler file under the `public void onClick(View v) {`