# Intent to launch alarm settings (in clock application) on Android

Tags: android

Here I have found how to launch a clock application [Intent to launch the clock application on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590955/intent-to-launch-the-clock-application-on-android)

But how to launch directly "Alarms" activity in clock application? I know it's possible, saw such application on market, but can't find proper solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the Following Code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
startActivity(i);
```

You can also set the alarm by doing something like below :

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm"); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 11); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 20); 
startActivity(i);
```

You will also need to have the following permission in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

For more information check the content [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you! Ohh... it was so easy.

Comment: you could accept it as answer if it worked for you :) This will help others who view this thread.

Comment: This sets an alarm automatically, without being able for the user to review some settings first, any way to show the 'confirmation' screen first?