# Open device clock from button

Tags: android, button, clock, system-clock

How can I open device clock from my activity .

I am making a simple app in which user can set alarms
For which I want to open device clock using onclicklistner I tried to search on google but didn't find anything.

Comment: Why dont you use the clock widget??

Comment: We cannot set alarm from clock widget

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) to set the alarm

Comment: But you can get the time selected and use the above link to set the alarm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every manufacturer has a different clock implementation.  You need to hardcode it like the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/1199931

Answer (score 3):

You can open alarm clock by setting the timer or without timer.Use the following code you will be able to achieve the alarm clock.
where timersec = time in seconds

**In java:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, timerSec);
startActivity(i);
```

**In kotlin:**

```
val i = Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER)
 i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_LENGTH, timerSec)
 startActivity(i)
```

add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```