# Get package name from Intent

Tags: android, clock

I am trying to get the package name of the default android clock (stock clock).

This is the intent I use to open the stock clock.

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
```

I have tried

```
i.getPackage();
```

But this returns null. Is there a way to get the package name of the default clock in android, in any phone?

Comment: Why do you need it? See this answer anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4281243/4059697

Comment: I am currently using this but this isnt a robust solution. There are some phones that arent covered in that list. - Even then, there should be a way to get the name of the package being opened from the intent, right?

Answer (score 4):

> But this returns null

That is because you have not set the package name in the `Intent`.

> Is there a way to get the package name of the default clock in android, in any phone?

Not really, as there is no concept of a "default clock" in Android.

However, you can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see what activities will respond to the `Intent` that you have constructed.

Comment: ^ Still not very helpful.  
`List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS), 0);`  

Printing resolvepackagename returns null. activityinfo returns something that doesnt help either.

Answer (score 3):

> Hope this will help you:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
List<ResolveInfo> packages = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : packages){

        String package_name = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        Log.w("Package Name: ",package_name);

    }
```