# How to use kivy to open default Android apps?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am currently developing an app for Android, and I would like to make it so that when the user clicks on a button within the app, they are redirected to the default Android clock app, where they can set up reminders for themselves. Is there any way that Kivy can access those default apps?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to construct an appropriate intent, as described at e.g. [Intent to launch the clock application on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590955/intent-to-launch-the-clock-application-on-android) , but you can do this from Python via pyjnius instead of by writing java code directly. I have an example that you might find useful [here](https://github.com/inclement/Kivy-keyboard-tester/blob/master/keyboardtester/main.py#L49), which creates an intent using pyjnius, but in this case for sending an email rather than opening an app.