# Android - How to set system Alarm Clock from my own app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I would like to set a normal, Android alarm clock in my app - the one in the default Android Clock application. I simply want to schedule a an alarm that will ring let's say tomorrow at 8 a.m. I've read about the Alarm Manager, but it seems to trigger an event, and I just want it to ring. I'm pretty sure there's an easy solution for that, but I couldn't find it. I'll apprecaite any help!

Comment: I think that does not work. You need to tell the alarm app (which is not always the same on every device) that it should ring. That app is not part of the Android API itself so you might need to build your own ringer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up building my own ringer in the BroadcastReceiver, as zapl suggested (thanks!). Problem was, I couldn't create a dialog that would allow user to dismiss the alarm, however I was able to create a notification that does that, as the class documentation suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no documented `Intent` for launching the alarm clock in the Android SDK. Having said that, here are a few resources you can try that should get you around that:

- [Intent to launch the clock application on android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3590955/1101070)
- [Android AlarmClock ACTION_SET_ALARM intent produces exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7305685/1101070)
- [How does one launch android version dependent alarm clock?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463317/1101070)