# Can I manage the AlarmClock in Android from my application?

Tags: java, android

I develop an application which must manage the Alarm Clock in Android. I specifically need to do the following:

- execute some code in my application when the user sets an alarm (also find out the time of the alarm at the moment of execution);
- cancel an alarm when the user pushes a specific button in my application;
- execute some code in my application when an alarm goes off.

I must mention that I am not interested in the CPU alarms, but the Alarm Clock application, which people use to wake up.

Comment: Looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618748/android-how-to-set-system-alarm-clock-from-my-own-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an alarm using the intent [described here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html).

However, you can not intercept the AlarmClock UI or ringing alarms as you seek to.

You might want to look into scheduling your own reminders, probably using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) with RTC_WAKEUP.